# How do I apply null annotations to a Java method that is exposed in an API?

Tags: java, jsr305

Say I have a class with an invariant that a certain instance variable is never null.  I also want to use jsr305 null annotations correctly.  The class is exposed as an API, so I cannot rely on the annotations to prevent nulls; I also need to check for null at runtime.

```
public final class NonNullString {
  private final String string;

  public NonNullString(String string) {
    if (string == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    this.string = string;
  }

  public String getString() {
    return string;
  }
}
```

What is the best way to apply null annotations to this class?  `@javax.annotation.Nonnull` applied to the parameter of the constructor describes my intent, but then Eclipse's null analysis warns that the null check is dead code.  I can suppress Eclipse's warnings, if necessary, but the warning made me wonder if there is a better way to use the annotations.

EDIT: I am asking how to handle the interface between client code that may not use null annotations and code that uses null annotations.

Comment: Lombok might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that Lombok can generate null checks from any annotation named NonNull or NotNull, which would work here.  I was looking for a more lightweight solution, though.

Comment: Not sure how much more lightweight you can get than inserting basic assertion statements at compile time.